# GoLang Printing a Directory Tree

Tags: go

I'm having trouble creating a recursive function in Go to print a directory with all its subdirectories and files. I got some issues with saving the current files or directory to the result. The following code is only printing level 0 directories.

```golang
func ListTree(path string, level int) (result string, err error) {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }
    for idx, entry := range files {
        result += fmt.Sprintf("\n%v/%v", MultiplyElement("\t", level), entry.Name())
        if entry.IsDir() {
            ListTree(path + "/" + entry.Name(),level+1)
        }
    }
    return result, err
}
```

However, when I declare the result variable outside the function (I know that's bad code, just for testing) it works perfectly, but the result value isn't cleared after calling the function.

```golang
var result string
func ListTree(path string, level int) (string, error) {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }
    for idx, entry := range files {
        result += fmt.Sprintf("\n%v/%v", MultiplyElement("\t", level), entry.Name())
        if entry.IsDir() {
            ListTree(path + "/" + entry.Name(),level+1)
        }
    }
    return result, err
}
```

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/xlab/treeprint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code sample, you're calling `ListTree` recursively but not using its return value, so anything computed and returned by calls at level > 0 is dropped on the floor.

Instead, try:

```
result += ListTree(path + "/" + entry.Name(),level+1)
```

Alternatively, use [filepath.Walk](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) to traverse a directory tree.

Answer (score 3):

You could use filepath.Walk.

```
filepath.Walk("/path/to/folder", func(name string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    fmt.Println(name)
    return nil
})
```